# Yii Prevent Form Submit on client side validation

Tags: php, jquery, validation, yii, client-side

I'm having an issue trying to make a client side validation on yii 1.1.12.
I have the following

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript
        ->registerCoreScript('jquery');
?>
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'my-form',
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
        'clientOptions'=> array('validateOnSubmit'=>true,
                                 'afterValidate'=>'js:function() 
                                        {     
                                           return false
                                        }'
                                ),
        'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
)); 
?>
```

Even using a return false in after validate, my form still being submitted.
Any way to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
 just removed

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript
        ->registerCoreScript('jquery');
?>
```

Comment: I told you, is not it? i am not writing my answer for decoration :)

Answer (score 4):

You may be going right way. But Yii client side validation also depends on the error you show in form. If your showing error using `CHtml::error()` method than for that variable client side validation will not happen. I can't say what you are using as you have not posted any code. So try Using `$form->error()` method.
Let me know if still your are facing problem.

Also check the link below given.

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript
        ->registerCoreScript('jquery');
?>
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'my-form',
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'clientOptions'=> array('validateOnSubmit'=>true),
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
)); 
?>
```

http://www.waytoblogger.com/blog/technical/yii/yii-client-side-validation/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'my-form',
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
)); 
?>
```

I see in `clientOptions` you are not doing any specific thing. So just removed. And you do not have to include jquery by yourself, As far as i know yii automatically includes it when it is required(Here activeform requires, I guess). 
You may have a look to this [url](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm)

Comment: It keeps submiting form. I have to set something more?

Comment: Can you remove this one and try it: `'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')`, because if form is file attachable then yii can not validate it on client side.
`

Comment: Do you have firebug, maybe you can have look and tell us the js error

Answer (score 0):

```
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
 'clientOptions' => array('validateOnSubmit'=>true),
```

Comment: Please explain your code a little, so people can understand it.